# Loading large datasets in Power BI Designer (Preview, 2.21)

Tags: powerbi

I'm just playing with Power BI designer and decided to throw my first real dataset at it.

It's fairly typical of our needs - an on-site hosted tabular model including a 70 million row fact table with a few simple measures and dimensions of moderate size.

Though I can successfully connect to the dataset, it starts to load all 70 million rows into the designer and takes a predictably long time doing so. I'm guessing that I've missed something fairy fundamental, because this behaviour makes it unusable, but I can't find anything that tells me what I'm doing wrong.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or direct me to the magic instruction that tells me how to connect to a dataset of this sort without loading the whole thing into the designer?

Thanks

Stuart

P.S. I've not installed any additional software, and fully expect that I will need to install the Power BI Analysis Services Connector once I want to deploy the report to the Power BI portal.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from Microsoft:

> At the moment, the Designer always imports and caches data so it's
>   loading it into memory. Not ideal I realise, and we're working on
>   allowing live connections to AS Tabular models.
>
> In the meantime, you can expose your AS Tabular model through to the
>   Power BI Service using the AS Connector and then build live reports
>   against it through the web interface. There's details on that here:
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbi/archive/2015/03/11/power-bi-analysis-services-connector-deep-dive.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Or you can build your reports in PowerView and publish those.  I find this to be the best way.